# Scanner not looking for input if given a mismatch first in a loop

Tags: java

Afternoon,
I'm having a strange issue with the scanner class that may or may not be my fault.
I made a scanner-like class that displays a prefix and error checks for the user.
The problem is, if an input throws an InputMismatchError, the code gets to the scanner line on the next try and never asks for an input. It just throws the mismatch error, and continues without waiting for a user input.

```
    public int readInt(String prefixString, int lowLimit, int highLimit)
{
    int number = 0;
    boolean validResponse=true;
    System.out.print(prefixString + ": ");
    do
    {
        try
        {
            number = scanner.nextInt();//this is what is causing the issue
            if(number<lowLimit || number>highLimit)
            {
                System.out.print(number + " is outside of the limits of " + lowLimit + "-" + highLimit + "\nPlease retry: ");
                validResponse=false;
            }
            else
            {
                validResponse=true;
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.print("The phrase entered is not a valid number." + "\n" + prefixString + ": ");
            validResponse = false;
        }

    } while (!validResponse);
    return number;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on why this is happening? Thanks!

Edit for legacy and others with the same problem:
The solution below only partially fixed the problem. It still happens, but less frequently. I switched to the BufferedReader class, which doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could skip one token when the front of the input is not a number:

```
    catch(InputMismatchException e)
    {
        System.out.print("The phrase entered is not a valid number." + "\n" + prefixString + ": ");
        validResponse = false;
        scanner.next();
    }
```

A token is the thing between two delimiters, which default to whitespace. See the documentation of the Scanner class for details and how to change it (`useDelimiter`).

Comment: I'll try that, I'm not too familiar with scanner's behavior, for I used a class similar to this for a long time, but I decided to make my own because it would crash on a mismatch.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. As a side note, if you don't like exceptions, you can also use the `hasNextInt` method before calling `nextInt`.

Comment: The exception is fine, it allows me to set the message differently when it doesn't match.